# What permissions are needed for an service account to generate signed url for blobs on cloud storage in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url

I would like to know exact permissions needed by a service account to be able to generate signed urls (GET and PUT) on any object in a specific bucket B1.
A terraform script is welcome.
Currently I just use default app engine service account which has a lot of extra permissions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate a GET signed url, your service account needs to have `storage.objects.get` permission

To generate a PUT signed url, your service account needs to have `storage.objects.create` permission

So ideally I would create a new role - `generate_signed_url` and grant these 2 permissions on that role. Then assign that role to the service account that's being used to generate a signed url.

Comment: To put it more simply, the service account needs the permission to do whatever would be done with the signed URL.

Comment: Is there any documentation laying around for this? Would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @ColeGulledge this page documents this answer but I think it's phrased strangely. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-gsutil